# How to make pypdf2 Annotations printable

Tags: python, pdf, acrobat, pypdf

I'm Using the `PyPDF2` Library to do some annotations to a pdf. Here's the code that I'm using

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import AnnotationBuilder



reader = PdfReader("Example.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]
writer = PdfWriter()
writer.add_page(page)


annotation = AnnotationBuilder.free_text(
    "Hello World",
    rect=(50, 550, 200, 650),
    font="Arial",
    bold=True,
    italic=True,
    font_size="20pt",
    font_color="00ff00",
    border_color="0000ff",
    background_color="cdcdcd",
)
writer.add_annotation(page_number=0, annotation=annotation)


with open("annotated-pdf.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

But the thing here is that The annotations are shown in the Acrobat reader

[image: the ss from the acrobat]

but when it comes to the printable preview the annotations are vanished. Is there any way that I can make those annotations printable

[image]

Comment: If it helps your searching, this is functionality is often called "flattening" of annotations.

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf